# Difference between group means and the total mean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to calculate various group statistics using pandas and put them into a new dataframe. For example, to calculate mean, median and count for var1 and var2 over group1 and group2 I use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["A","C",2,5],
                   ["A","C",4,3],
                   ["B","C",3,1],
                   ["B","D",1,2],
                   ["A","D",5,1],
                   ["B","D",3,4]], columns=["group1", "group2", "var1", "var2"])

df.groupby(["group1", "group2"]).agg(["mean", "median", "count"])
```

And the resulting dataframe is:

```
              var1              var2             
              mean median count mean median count
group1 group2                                    
A      C       3.0    3.0     2  4.0    4.0     2
       D       5.0    5.0     1  1.0    1.0     1
B      C       3.0    3.0     1  1.0    1.0     1
       D       2.0    2.0     2  3.0    3.0     2
```

I would like to add a custom function to groupby agg (or apply) that also calculates the difference between the group mean and the total mean for each included variable (var1 and var2 in the case above).

Total means in this case are:

```
df[["var1", "var2"]].mean()

var1    3.000000
var2    2.666667
```

The function for agg/apply would need to obtain these total means, subtract them from the corresponding mean columns for each group and add the resulting mean_diff column to the dataframe above.

So my expected output is:

```
              var1                        var2             
              mean mean_diff median count mean  mean_diff  median count
group1 group2                                                        
A      C       3.0       0.0    3.0     2  4.0   1.333333     4.0     2
       D       5.0       2.0    5.0     1  1.0  -1.666667     1.0     1
B      C       3.0       0.0    3.0     1  1.0  -1.666667     1.0     1
       D       2.0      -1.0    2.0     2  3.0   0.333333     3.0     2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom function and a global variable:

```
global_mean = df[["var1", "var2"]].mean()

def mean_diff(g):
    return g.mean()-global_mean[g.name]
    
df.groupby(["group1", "group2"]).agg(["mean", mean_diff, "median", "count"])
```

Or modifying the output after aggregation:

```
def mean_diff(g):
    return g.mean()
    
out = df.groupby(["group1", "group2"]).agg(["mean", mean_diff, "median", "count"])

cols = out.filter(like='mean_diff').columns
out[cols] = out[cols].sub(df[['var1', 'var2']].mean().values, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
              var1                        var2                       
              mean mean_diff median count mean mean_diff median count
group1 group2                                                        
A      C       3.0       0.0    3.0     2  4.0  1.333333    4.0     2
       D       5.0       2.0    5.0     1  1.0 -1.666667    1.0     1
B      C       3.0       0.0    3.0     1  1.0 -1.666667    1.0     1
       D       2.0      -1.0    2.0     2  3.0  0.333333    3.0     2
```